# Change Title With Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-title

How can I modify the existing title to the document with Jquery as mouseover title change like that on facebook title link.

Comment: You can see an example jQuery code [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2012/12/change-document-tab-title-jquery.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the page title with Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173596/changing-the-page-title-with-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Answer (score 40):

You don't need jQuery.

```
document.title = 'My new title here';
```

Answer (score 11):

With javascript. jQuery won't help you here:

```
document.title = 'New Title';
```

You can insert that into a jQuery mouseover callback function if you want.

Answer (score 7):

I'll extend on these other answers, this code should do it in entirety, just be sure to change the class in the selector, and the new Title Text.

```
(function(){
    var oldtitle;
    jQuery('a.yourlink').hover(
        function () {
           oldtitle = document.title;
           document.title = 'Your New Title';
        },
        function () {
            document.title = oldtitle;
        }
    );
})();
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo I made that changes the text of the object, rather than the window title: http://jsfiddle.net/MpZGf/1/

Comment: It looks like `oldTitle` will be out of scope when it's needed the second time.

Comment: This won't work.  oldtitle won't exist when the 2nd function is called.  You have to move oldtitle up to a higher scope or save it somewhere else.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to wrap the lot in a function and not have to attach extra 'properties' to the document like here - http://jsfiddle.net/aranm/gUsnC/2/

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
document.title = 'title';
```