# Changing the page title with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, title

How to make dynamic changing `<title>` tag with jquery?

example: adding 3 `>` symbols one by one

```
> title
>> title
>>> title
```

Answer (score 207, accepted):

```
$(document).prop('title', 'test');
```

This is simply a JQuery wrapper for:

```
document.title = 'test';
```

To add a > periodically you can do:

```
function changeTitle() {
    var title = $(document).prop('title'); 
    if (title.indexOf('>>>') == -1) {
        setTimeout(changeTitle, 3000);  
        $(document).prop('title', '>'+title);
    }
}

changeTitle();
```

Comment: Might it not be better to use setInterval and clearInterval rather than a string of setTimeouts?

Comment: What are the implications on SEO calling the page via jQuery?

Answer (score 23):

There's no need to use jQuery to change the title. Try:

```
document.title = "blarg";
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready) for more details.

To dynamically change on button click:

```
$(selectorForMyButton).click(function(){
    document.title = "blarg";
});
```

To dynamically change in loop, try:

```
var counter = 0;

var titleTimerId = setInterval(function(){
    document.title = document.title + '>';
    counter++;
    if(counter == 5){
        clearInterval(titleTimerId);
    }
}, 100);
```

To string the two together so that it dynamically changes on button click, in a loop:

```
var counter = 0;

$(selectorForMyButton).click(function(){
  titleTimerId = setInterval(function(){
    document.title = document.title + '>';
    counter++;
    if(counter == 5){
        clearInterval(titleTimerId);
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: when user click on button, title will be changed like in question, and this changing will be looped

Answer (score 5):

using

```
$('title').html("new title");
```

Comment: i know, but how make it dynamically?

Comment: well this IS dynamic, ie with Javascript. Would you by chance mean "animated"?

Comment: @IIya: give more markup and code for better answer . your questions unclear.

Answer (score 3):

```js
 var isOldTitle = true;
        var oldTitle = document.title;
        var newTitle = "New Title";
        var interval = null;
        function changeTitle() {
            document.title = isOldTitle ? oldTitle : newTitle;
            isOldTitle = !isOldTitle;
        }
        interval = setInterval(changeTitle, 700);

        $(window).focus(function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
            $("title").text(oldTitle);
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Html code:

```
Change Title:
<input type="text" id="changeTitle" placeholder="Enter title tag">
<button id="changeTitle1">Click!</button>
```

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#changeTitle1").click(function() {
        $(document).prop('title',$("#changeTitle").val()); 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

i use (and recommend):

```
$(document).attr("title", "Another Title");
```

and it works in IE as well
this is an alias to

```
document.title = "Another Title";
```

Some will debate on wich is [better, prop or attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr), and since prop call DOM properties and attr Call HTML properties, i think this is actually better...

use this after the DOM Load

```
$(function(){
    $(document).attr("title", "Another Title");
});
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Some code to walk through a list of titles (circularily or one-shot):

```
    var titles = [
            " title",
            "> title",
            ">> title",
            ">>> title"
    ];

    // option 1:
    function titleAniCircular(i) {
            // from first to last title and back again, forever
            i = (!i) ? 0 : (i*1+1) % titles.length;
            $('title').html(titles[i]);
            setTimeout(titleAniCircular, 1000, [i]);
    };

    // option 2:
    function titleAniSequence(i) {
            // from first to last title and stop
            i = (!i) ? 0 : (i*1+1);
            $('title').html(titles[i]);
            if (i<titles.length-1) setTimeout(titleAniSequence, 1000, [i]);
    };

    // then call them when you like.
    // e.g. to call one on document load, uncomment one of the rows below:

    //$(document).load( titleAniCircular() );
    //$(document).load( titleAniSequence() );
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this one:

```
document.title = "your_customize_title";
```

Answer (score 1):

Its very simple way to change the page title with jquery..

```
<a href="#" id="changeTitle">Click!</a>
```

Here the Jquery method:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#changeTitle").click(function() {
       $(document).prop('title','I am New One');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.title="your title";
```

I prefer this.

Comment: This is just a repeat of the existing answers.