# How do I give an ID to part of the contents of a <title> tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a title tag that looks something like this:

```
<title>My Page Title - Photo #3</title>
```

I want to use JavaScript to change the numeric part of it, without having to hard code the "My Page Title - Photo #" string which is generated server side.

I tried wrapping the number in a span so that I could change the contents of the span:

```
<title>My Page Title - Photo #<span class="photoid">3</span></title>
```

But it seems HTML is not allowed in the `title` tag. I'd really like to pursue the class approach if possible as that would allow me to use a line of jquery such as this:

```
$('.photoid').html(new_photoid);
```

Did I mention that the photoid appears in several places on the page, which is why I want to be able to use this oneliner to change them all at the same time? For example:

```
<p>A paragraph also containing the number <span class="photoid">3</span></p>
```

Comment: So, you have the number in the title and also other elements that have that number in them (i.e. you don't have `<title>` tags in your `<body>` do you?)?

Comment: @JustcallmeDrago: Correct, clarified with an example.

Comment: Wait, are you asking about the `<title>` or about `<p>` elements? If you just want regular elements in the `<body>`, then what's wrong with your code? Did you even try it?

Answer (score 0):

A title can only have text, so you need to parse it out.

```
document.title = document.title.replace(/\d+$/, "new value");
```

Comment: Finally a vallina JS solution.

Answer (score 0):

title can't be set like that,
it's not a child of .html

some thing like

```
var num = 3;
document.title = "foo "+num
```

to set the title, then reuse num for these photoids.

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery onDocumentReady syntax:

```
$(function () {
    var elements = $('.contains_photoid');
    elements.html(elements.html().replace("3", "4"));

    $(document).attr('title', $(document).attr('title').replace("3", "4"));
});
```

You can't see the title change in this example, but that is the syntax. See [Changing the page title with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173596/changing-the-page-title-with-jquery)

The `"3"` and `"4"` can be changed to anything, so you can create the page with a unique character string in place of the real ID in order to easily replace it if it appears in text with numbers already in it.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZmXj5/1/

Comment: There's really no reason to use `.ready()` to set the `title`.

Comment: I threw it in there because that's closer to changing all occurences "at the same time" than if it wasn't.

Comment: I see. I missed that you were also setting the other elements at once.

Answer (score 0):

**Javascript**

```
var photoID = 355; //this assumes you have some code where you set this photoID value
var title = document.title;
title = title.substr(0,title.lastIndexOf('#')+1);
document.title = title+photoID;
```

See this fiddle for proof: **http://jsfiddle.net/xrkhA/**
(I used a div content because you can't use title in jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0):

You can either use, but $('title') will fail in IE8

```
document.title="new title";
```

or

```
$('title').html('new title');
```

or

```
$(document).attr('title','new title');
```