# Automated Breadcrumb Titles

Tags: javascript, breadcrumbs

I implemented the following script on my website. It creates automated breadcrumbs. The problem I'm having is the titles it generates. For the page you are currently on, it displays the page title which is fine. For the index files it uses the root folder names instead of the page title which is what I want it to do. For an example;

This is what it is out putting now.

Home / art / Painting

Painting I'm fine with it is the page title. Art is the folder name but I would like it to be the page title. Home I'm using a Font Awesome Icon and Im fine with that.

This is what Id like it to output

Home / Art Department / Painting

Art Department being the page title.

Here is the Javascript.

```js
function breadcrumbs(){
  sURL = new String;
  bits = new Object;
  var x = 0;
  var stop = 0;
 var output = '<a href="http://test.ccri.edu/"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i></a> &nbsp;/&nbsp; '; 
  sURL = location.href;
  sURL = sURL.slice(8,sURL.length); 
  chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
  sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length)
  while(!stop){
    chunkStart = sURL.indexOf("/");
    if (chunkStart != -1){
      bits[x] = sURL.slice(0,chunkStart)
      sURL = sURL.slice(chunkStart+1,sURL.length);
    }else{
      stop = 1;
    }
    x++;
  }
  for(var i in bits){
    output += "<a href=\"";
    for(y=1;y<x-i;y++){
      output += "../";
    }
    output += bits[i] + "/\">" + bits[i] + "</a> &nbsp;/&nbsp; ";
  }
  document.write(output + document.title);
}
  
<!--
breadcrumbs();
 -->
</script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any libraries like jquery or frameworks like angular

Comment: Yes, Jquery. The code is working fine I just want to change it a little bit and my Javascript skills art not very good.

Comment: Look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173596/changing-the-page-title-with-jquery

Comment: Jquery documentation for it is here http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: Thanks Binvention... still not sure how to implement that in my own code.

Comment: Okay are you just ting to change the one reference art to Art Department?

Comment: I want it to display the page title instead of the folder title.

Comment: Are you meaning the actual html title or your links that are being displayed

Comment: Because your breadcrumbs function is just appending links to the document

Comment: Yea the html title that is in your head code.

Comment: You do realize that the document title property is used in your breadcrumbs function so if you change your title your output on your breadcrumbs won't be what you want you'd have to change it outside of your breadcrumbs function and if your breadcrumbs is run multiple times it wouldn't give you the output you want.