# How to replace page title dynamically by popup box title?

Tags: php, jquery, popup, popupwindow, page-title

My index page contains popup box. I want to replace index page title by popup box title if popup box clicked.

For example

```
<title><?php echo $title?></title>
```

I want to display as following:

```
<?php
    if(condition){      (->*such as #model2 is clicked*)
        $title="Model2 Section";
    }
    else{
        $title="Home"
    }
?>
```

I have used popup box as following:->
**(link for popup box)**

```
<article>
<a href="#modal2" class="dsnbutton ybank" id="pop_button">Model 2</a>
</article>
```

**popup box**

```
<div class="remodal" data-remodal-id="modal2" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal2Title" aria-describedby="modal2Desc">
```

**How to change title ?** Any Idea.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Just to be clear - you're asking how to echo a PHP variable in to some HTML?

Comment: Yes @RoryMcCrossan I want to echo php variable. I want to change page title dynamically. Let me clarify clearly, the title of default page is home, and if popup window is displayed (through #href tag), I want to change and echo another title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the page title with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173596/changing-the-page-title-with-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in JavaScript with `document.title = "new title"`

Comment: Thanks @Nick De Jaeger, but does it compatible with SEO ?