# Trying to set up randomized text. What's wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to set up something that essentially chooses from a set of predefined phrases and displays it as a subheader on my page. What did I do wrong here?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function RandomQuote()
        {
        var quotes= new Array();
        quotes[0] = 'Home of Fall!'
        quotes[1] = 'At Least This is Something!'
        quotes[2] = 'Javascript!'
        quotes[3] = 'Railroads at Last!'
        quotes[4] = 'Better than Wikipedia'
        quotes[5] = 'Now with Scorpions!'
        quotes[6] = 'Irrelevant Stuff!'
        quotes[7] = 'Fall is here!'
        quotes[8] = 'That moment when Image-908329490283094.jpg'
        quotes[9] = 'With Added Roundness!'
        quotes[10] = 'Bacon!'
        quotes[11] = 'Try Out WinterNstuff!'
        quotes[12] = 'Try Out SpringNstuff!'
        quotes[13] = 'Try Out SummerNstuff!'
        quotes[14] = 'all html is lowercase!'
        quotes[15] = '<div id=''youWishYouCouldReadThis''>InsertCodeHere</div>'
        quotes[16] = 'In Remembrance of the soldiers who died in the Iranian War'
        quotes[17] = 'Leaf Me Alone!'
        quotes[18] = 'Pumpkins Were So 2011.'
        quotes[19] = 'This Does not Count as a Random String'
        quotes[20] = 'With Added Content Generation!'

    return quotes[Math.floor((Math.random() * 19.9999))];
}
    </script>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="header">
    <table style="background-color:blue">
    String:
    <script type="text/javascript">document.write(RandomQuote());</script>
    </table>
    </body>
</div>
</div>
```

As a followup, is there a way to configure a title to do the same thing with random string generation?

Comment: I did not understand your follow up thought. What do you want to do with title? Do you want to put the value from random string generation in title?

Comment: @Ranjith Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. Can you call functions and script in titles?

Comment: Nope. What you need to do is that call it from a script tag. and append the value to title. Use JQuery as it is very good for stuff like this. Look here for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/HCCSW/4/ What you want is called DOM manipulation. Read about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quotes[15] should have double quotes, or you need to escape the single quotes

```
quotes[15] = '<div id=\'youWishYouCouldReadThis\'>InsertCodeHere</div>'
```

or

```
quotes[15] = '<div id="youWishYouCouldReadThis">InsertCodeHere</div>'
```

P.S. your body/div closing tags are not in the correct order

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8kTAH/) is your code working.

Comment: For your follow up, check out the examples [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715339/change-title-with-javascript)

Comment: Also have a look at @Jan Dvorak's suggestions for improvements to your code

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape quotes in quotes[15]. Here is a working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ranjith19/HCCSW/

```
function RandomQuote()
    {
    var quotes= new Array();
    quotes[0] = 'Home of Fall!'
    quotes[1] = 'At Least This is Something!'
    quotes[2] = 'Javascript!'
    quotes[3] = 'Railroads at Last!'
    quotes[4] = 'Better than Wikipedia'
    quotes[5] = 'Now with Scorpions!'
    quotes[6] = 'Irrelevant Stuff!'
    quotes[7] = 'Fall is here!'
    quotes[8] = 'That moment when Image-908329490283094.jpg'
    quotes[9] = 'With Added Roundness!'
    quotes[10] = 'Bacon!'
    quotes[11] = 'Try Out WinterNstuff!'
    quotes[12] = 'Try Out SpringNstuff!'
    quotes[13] = 'Try Out SummerNstuff!'
    quotes[14] = 'all html is lowercase!'
    quotes[15] = '<div id=\'youWishYouCouldReadThis\'>InsertCodeHere</div>'
    quotes[16] = 'In Remembrance of the soldiers who died in the Iranian War'
    quotes[17] = 'Leaf Me Alone!'
    quotes[18] = 'Pumpkins Were So 2011.'
    quotes[19] = 'This Does not Count as a Random String'
    quotes[20] = 'With Added Content Generation!'

return quotes[Math.floor((Math.random() * 19.9999))];
    }
```

Comment: My problem is that it isn't showing any strings whatsoever. Even after removing quote #15 entirely, it doesn't seem to be working. Ideas?

Comment: You need to call the function from some where. You have created a function, now you need to call it from somewhere

Answer (score 2):

Quote #15 should have proper quotes:

```
quotes[15] = '<div id="youWishYouCouldReadThis">InsertCodeHere</div>';
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you are generating an index from 0..19.999 so `quotes[20]` will never be used.

The best solution would be

```
return quotes[Math.random()*quotes.length];
```

Second, as mentioned by others, the quote #15 is not properly escaped:

```
quotes[15] = '<div id=''youWishYouCouldReadThis''>InsertCodeHere</div>'
```

should be

```
quotes[15] = '<div id=\'youWishYouCouldReadThis\'>InsertCodeHere</div>'
```

or

```
quotes[15] = '<div id="youWishYouCouldReadThis">InsertCodeHere</div>'
```

Third, there are easier ways to create a fixed array:

```
quotes = [
  'Home of Fall!',
  'At least This is Something!',
  ...
  'With Added Content Generation'
]
```

Fourth, you shouldn't be placing a bare text inside the `<table>`. A `<p>` tag would be better in your case.

Fifth, your closing tags are not in the correct order. Credits go to @rlay3 for noticing this.