# How to change browser tab to current email subject for gmail

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to have my browser tab title for Gmail show the Subject for the current email because I have software that helps time tracking by capturing tab titles. Unfortunately, it shows Inbox (6) - my.name@mycompany.com all the time.

I see [Change Title With Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6715339/change-title-with-javascript) provides javascript to change the tab title to alternative text. How would I get the Subject of the current message in Gmail in a Gmail add-on?

Comment: could you share a bit of your code please?

Comment: Did that answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are retrieving a message of type [`GmailMessage`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) and that you are running your js client side in an HTML context such as a webapp you could:

- create a function in app script that calls the method `getSubject()`
- Serve HTML
- call backend function with `google.script.run`
- call a success handler that changes title when async function is completed with success.

in your HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
      function onSuccess(subject) {
        document.title = subject
      }
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .getSubject();
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and in your .gs

```
getSubject(){
 //get your message here
 return (message.getSubject());
}
```

REFERENCES

- [Serving HTML on web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)