# How to change the title of the website by value of a textbox?

Tags: javascript, html

Just like when you ask a question on this website, as you type the title in the tab changes to whatever you have typed in the question box.  How do you access this?

Comment: Are you talking about autosuggest - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

Comment: Set the `document.title` field.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick'n'dirty:

```
document.title = prompt('sup bro ?');
```

---

If you don't want a modal input dialog, you need to catch some events for any `<input>` box.

```
document.getElementById('inputBoxId').addEventListener('keypress', function( event ) {
    if( event.keyCode === 13 ) {  // return ?
        document.title = this.value;
    }
}, false);
```

<sup>`addEventListener` needs to get replaced by `attachEvent` for IE<9</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('myTextbox')
function setTitle () {
  document.title = textbox.value
}
textbox.onkeyup = setTitle
textbox.onchange = setTitle
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your title tag, in html dynamic, So the title tag which appears as a element of head tag. You have to either use javascript or some server language to set its value.

Answer (score 0):

Here,

```
<script language="javascript">
 document.title = "The new title goes here.";
</script>
```

Just add this in your page and try!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a server side scripting like `PHP` or `ASP`, its quite simple. Just generate a text based on your URL.

For example, if you have a php page `mypage.php`, you may use;

```
<title><?php echo $_GET["title"]; ?></title> //will display page title "MyPage"
```

if you call your php page like `mypage.php?title=MyPage`

Not JavaScript, but just for your information.