# Reading HTML header info of files via JS

Tags: javascript, header

I have a product list that is generated by asp
I have product description for each product in a html file

```
each html file is named: <product.id>.html<br/>
html file size is only 1-3 kb
```

Within the html file is `<title>` and `<meta name="description" content="..." />`
I want to access these in an efficient way so that I can output this as e.g.:

```
document.write(<product.id>.html.title);<br/>
document.write(<product.id>.html.description);
```

I have a working solution for the individual product, where I use the description file - but hope to find a more efficient / simple approach. Preferably, I want to avoid having 30+ hidden iframes - google might think that I am trying to tamper with search result and blacklist my page...

Current code:

```
<iframe src="myfile.html" id="product" style="display:none">&nbsp;</iframe>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById('product').onload = function(){
   var d = window.frames[frame].document;
   var title = d.title : ' ';
   var keywords = d.getElementsByName('keywords')[0].getAttribute('content', 0) : ' ';
   var descript = d.getElementsByName('description')[0].getAttribute('content', 0) : ' ';
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code does not close the open `function(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this solution:

```
<script>
  var xhr = $.ajax({ 
  type: "GET", 
  url: "/files/billeder/ecom/beskrivelser/<!--@Ecom:Group.Number-->.html", 
  success: function(msg){
    msg = msg.split('content="')[1];
    msg = msg.split('"')[0];
    document.getElementById("a_<!--@Ecom:Group.Number-->").innerHTML = "<p>" + msg + "</p>";
```

Not yet very elegant... but it works...

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here on another [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title), you could use:

```
document.title = "This is the new page title.";
```

and looking [here](http://www.blog.highub.com/mobile-2/a-fix-for-iphone-viewport-scale-bug/) gives us :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta').content = "New content here";
```

or:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('meta').name = "NewName";
```

With these, you should be able to read and write your tags as needed, I've only used a few examples here, there's surely more.

Answer (score 0):

You could load your files with AJAX. For example (using jQuery):

```
$.get('myfile.html', function(data){
   var title = $(data).find('head title').text();
   var keywords = $(data).find('head meta[name="keywords"]').attr('content');
   var descript = $(data).find('head meta[name="description"]').attr('content');
});
```

Here you find the jQuery documentation about using [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: I have tried to add this: `<script> $.get('files/Billeder/Ecom/Beskrivelser/<!--@Ecom:Group.Number-->.html', function(data){ document.write($(data).find('head meta[name="description"]').attr('content')); } </script>` But without any success... any ideas?

Comment: What is `<!--@Ecom:Group.Number-->`?

Comment: The `<!--@Ecom:Group.Number-->` just inserts product.id - on the server side the current script is:
`<script> document.write($.get('files/Billeder/Ecom/Beskrivelser/<!--@Ecom:Group.Number-->.html', function(data){ document.write($(data).find('head meta[name="description"]').attr('content')); }); </script>`

Comment: Well... this does not answers my question.

Comment: Sorry: The <!--@Ecom:Group.Number--> just inserts product.id - on the server side

Comment: And what is not working? Does the ajax request fail? Or is `data` in callback method empty?