# set meta tage dynamic page with javascript

Tags: javascript

i want to change title in every page of my code but when i view source code i still see the old title.
here is my code:

```
window.onload = function (){
      setProductMeta();
 }
function setProductMeta(){
    var des = document.getElementById("description").setAttribute("content","dynamic meta description");
    document.getElementById("keywords").setAttribute("content","dynamic meta keywords");
    document.title = "Point of Sale System";
}
```

and this meta tage above

```
<title>Welcome to Atmostphere Technology</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta id="title" name="title" content="Welcome to Atmostphere Technology" />
<meta id="description" name="description" content="atmos is best service in cambodia" />
<meta id="keywords" name="keywords" content="atmos is best service in cambodia" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Answer (score 0):

The server delivers the source code to the browser.

The browser converts the markup in to a DOM.

**Then** JavaScript runs and any DOM manipulation you perform is performed. It never touches the source code.

While it is sometimes useful to change the title with JavaScript (e.g. Facebook do it to indicate the number of alerts since the page was last interacted with), almost everything that consumes meta data does not execute JavaScript. If you want to change something fundamental about the page, do it in the source code, not with client side programming.

Comment: Yes. I have an idea. I wrote it down in the answer. To repeat it: Don't use client side programming when the most important consumers of the page won't execute it.

Comment: I have no idea how you are producing your source code. Assuming you are doing it by hand: Open text editor. Open your HTML document. Place cursor at the end of the title. Press backspace until you reach the beginning of the title. Type the new title.

Comment: `<title>The title you want</title>`