# Changing title without reloading the webpage

Tags: jquery, html, title

can anyone tell me how can I make the title of a webpage change without reloading.

Like in this blog: http://melvinencarnacion.tumblr.com/ ; the title changes as the songs name, and it is continuously changing.

It would be helpful if its client side independent code, like using window.history.pushState() which I don't know how to implement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: If you want to help SEO, then you will need to change the page title in the back-end and serve different versions of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this to change the title

```
document.title = "Your new title";
```

Do not use
`$('title').text('New Title')`
 because IE doesn't support it.

See [this page](http://homepage.ntlworld.com/kayseycarvey/document2.html) more details.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the `title` property on `document`.

```
document.title = 'new title';
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the title:

`document.title = "page title"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change it.

Try this:

$("title").text("hello world");

Comment: Way more overhead than needed.