# Dynamically change <title> on link click without reloading any content

Tags: javascript, jquery

**TL;DR**

What is the best way to change a page's `<title>` tag when a link is clicked but page content is not re-loaded (simply shown/hidden via CSS)? Some JavaScript, I would assume?

---

On this page (http://www.ukipme.com/pub-marine.php) I have two methods for viewing individual magazines. Clicking on the magazine cover on the right completely re-loads the page with a query string (e.g. `?mag=1`) appended to the URL and we have set the `<title>` tag to change then, but this was additional functionality we added via PHP. The framework's original method of changing content was simply to change shown/hidden content via CSS (basic JavaScript to add and remove an `active` class) by clicking on the left-hand tabs.

However, I would like for the page title to change when these left-hand tabs are clicked, also. The HTML code for the tabs is as follows:

```
<ul class="tab-nav three columns">
    <li class="active" ><a href="#" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60">Electric &amp; Hybrid Marine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60">Marine Catering</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60">Marine Maintenance</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60">Shipping Port</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60">ALL TITLES</a></li>
</ul>
```

And for their content:

```
<div class="tab-content nine columns">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="twelve columns">
            <a href="?mag=1"><img src="../img/covers/evm.jpg" alt="Electric &amp; Hybrid Marine" style="margin: 0 10px 10px 0;" /></a>
            <a href="?mag=2"><img src="../img/covers/mci.jpg" alt="Marine Catering" style="margin: 0 10px 10px 0;" /></a>
            <a href="?mag=3"><img src="../img/covers/mmi.jpg" alt="Marine Maintenance" style="margin: 0 10px 10px 0;" /></a>
            <a href="?mag=4"><img src="../img/covers/spi.jpg" alt="Shipping Port" style="margin: 0 10px 10px 0;" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried investigating, and I think something needs to happen in the `DOM`, but my JavaScript knowledge is unfortunately, almost completely non-existent. Can anyone kindly help?

**EDIT:**

I've tried changing my `<a>` tags to the following, but this doesn't seem to do anything:

```
<a onclick="window.document.title='<?=$title?> | UKIP Media &amp; Events'" href="#" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60"></a>
```

(`$title` is a PHP variable set on page load)

**SECOND EDIT @MGA**

My link now looks like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changetitle()" class="skip" gumby-goto="#top_of_page" gumby-offset="-60">
```

With this script at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changetitle() {
        document.title = "<?=$title?> | UKIP Media &amp; Events";
    }
</script>
```

But still nothing happens?

Comment: Here is the way you can change the Title by JavaScript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Comment: I had a look at this question, but unfortunately it turned in to a discussion on how this method is bad for SEO, and so a full answer never seemed to be given. I see that I should use `document.title`, but: Where? How? When?

Comment: Just everywhere, in your case, the best thing will be on the document ready event (jQuery). Than you can read your `mag` Parameter an then change the Title with `document.title = "I'm your Title"`.

Answer (score 1):

if i run this on your site, the effect is as desired, i think:

```
$('.tab-nav a').each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', function() {
        document.title = $(this).text() + ' | UKIP Media & Events';
    });
});
```

you could just put this in the document ready block of your general JS code.
granted, this is a little hacky.

---

combining this with your approach, the link would be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changetitle($(this).text());" ...>
```

and the changetitle function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changetitle(title) {
        document.title = title + " | UKIP Media & Events";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

function changetitle(value)
        {
            document.title = value;
        }

Call this method on your onClick() method of link, and pass the value(new title)
and keep this method either in your JS script file or write in script tag on HTML

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Please could you take a look at my second edit and let me know where I'm going wrong with your method?

Comment: Try if this works ? <script type="text/javascript">
    function changetitle() {
        document.title = "ABC";
    }
</script>

Comment: Unfortunately not, no.

Comment: If you are working with forms or iframes, try parent.document.title = "Value"