# Dynamic title of master page from jquery in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to give the dynamic title from javascript of a master page. Whenever I am doing from code behind like this:

```
   this.Master.Page.Title = "Yellow Page home, Gangtok, India | CliqueCity.com";
```

I have googled for solution but unable to get. I know this is so simple to add dynamic title from java script. My simple question is how can I add title from javascript

Comment: maybe this would help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Answer (score 0):

Simply select the title using jQuery

```
$('title').text('Hello');
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jQuery, you can add/use this:

```
$(document).attr("title", "New Title");
```

"New Title" represents title which you want to give to your page

Comment: Add some details about your answer