# Set HTML <title> tag values dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, page-title

I have an HTML page. The aim is to set the `<title>` tag dynamically.

Using this Ajax call to get data to be inserted inside title tag as below

```js
    $.get("/" + $.flydubai.config.CurrentLanguageCode + "/error/PageTitle/", function (data) {
        document.title = data;
    });
```

Now, I want to update *not* the browser title but the HTML `<title></title>` tag itself. Is it even possible? I tried these:

```js
document.getElementById('ttl').innerHTML = 'World';
ttl.innerHTML = 'world';
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = 'world';
document.querySelector.apply(document,['title']).innerHTML = 'world';
document.querySelectorAll.apply(document,['title'])[0].innerHTML = 'world';
```

These all will change only the client side (i.e., browser title).

Comment: Of course they change the browser title. What 'd you expect? The purpose of that title tag, is to show a title in the browser.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: @isherwood "All these characters" are actually 5 different solutions for the same problem. So if you pick one, it's not that many anymore. And especially `ttl.innerHTML = 'world'` isn't that much longer than `$('#ttl').html('world')`. :p

Comment: `$('#ttl').html('World')` beats `document.getElementById('ttl').innerHTML = 'World'`, no? Seems you truncated the statement a bit.

Comment: @GolezTrol ever heard about SEO ?

Comment: Robots doesn't have JavaScript activated if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @GolezTrol tats my question mate,any other options u know, to make this dynamic ?

Comment: Change the title server side.

Comment: its plain HTML page,server side codes not applicable

Comment: Downvoters , can i please have an reason,where am i wrong ?

Comment: If your goal is to change the contents of the `<title>` tag  but to leave the original, unmodified contents of the `<title>` tag visible to users, the answer is "That's not possible."   If that's not your goal, can you please clarify what you mean by "I want to update NOT the browser title but the HTML tag itself"?

Comment: Well. Google announced that they will try to add Javascript execution to their crawlers, so it might work. Your code changes the DOM, and that triggers changing the title in the browser as well as (hopefully) for the crawler. Mind though, if you add code that is specifically designed to give Google a different result than the regular visitor, you might get penalized, causing your site to drop in the search results.

Comment: For the record, you can change the DOM (in memory object representation of the document), but you cannot change the plain HTML through Javascript. No problem there, since Google will probably also use the processed DOM once they start executing Javascript in their crawlers.

Comment: @DanielBeck ok lets say i want to update both,browser title as well as Tag contents,any solution ?

Comment: @sajanyamaha `document.title="new title"` will do that.  (The browser title and the contents of the `<title>` tag are the same thing; I'm still not clear on the distinction you're trying to draw there.)

Comment: You might find this question useful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Answer (score 1):

You can't change text within the  tag without the browser detecting and refreshing it.

If you need to change a  tag and that tag must be yes or yes at the , then add a second title tag.

If you utilize:

```
document.title='my new title';
```

Changes will only be made to your first  tag.

Though I don't see any major benefit, that is the purpose of title tag, change the window title.

Also, when you want only to modify text, use `.innerText` rather than `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Create reusable function with variable to hold text
function title(text) {
    return document.title = text
}

// Call function with string in parenthesis 
title("Hello World");
```

Comment: You should explain your answer, not just a "code dump" like this.  It will help future users with their research.

Answer (score 0):

This is how can change title on particular page. Also, you can also push dynamic values from backend accordingly to change title value for particular search or result on particular page.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        document.title = 'Your title here.....';
    });
</script>
```