# Changing tab title on intervals [in javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, intervals, title

I know how to set intervals, but I can't quite figure out how to change the title on every interval.

My intended behavior for this is to (in my case), change the tab to welcome in English, then in Japanese (I already have a Japanese translation that is accurate), then to French, then back to English again.

It cycles through 3 different languages for the title of the tab.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455248/set-html-title-tag-values-dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this.
Replace console log with your title change.

```
let greatings = ['Hello English', 'Hello Japanese',     
'Hello French'];
let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(greatings[i++]);
    i = i == greatings.length ? 0 : i;
}, 3000);
```