# How can I dynamicly change the <title> tag?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, title

Please I wanna know how to change the  inside the  dynamically in angularjs.

I'm using the NGresource and pulling json data from the back-end and i want to change it dynamically then i go to a new article for example.

Comment: You might be able to just use some old fashioned javascript. Here's a related post.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change header based on angularjs partial view?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506329/how-to-dynamically-change-header-based-on-angularjs-partial-view)

Comment: not duplicated because am asking about pulling data from a resource and put it as title element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the HTML title and head elements on a per-view basis by using [angularjs-viewhead](https://github.com/apparentlymart/angularjs-viewhead).

here how to use it.

1. put the angularjs-viewhead.js in your asset folder
2. Declare as a dependency of your application as normal

   > var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ng', 'viewhead']);
3. This sort of setup can be achieved in an AngularJS application using the view-title directive. First, set up your title element to bind to the special scope variable viewTitle, which will be set when a tilted view is instantiated:

```
   </title ng-bind-template="{{viewTitle}} - FooBaz">FooBaz</title>
```

4. With this in place, add to each view's template a single view-title element setting the view's title:

```
   <view-title>About</view-title>
```

Comment: Thank you but what if i wanna inject a <link> or <meta> !

Comment: To add per-view metadata elements to the HTML head, place them near the top of your view template (it doesn't really matter where you put them as long as the are directly in the view scope, not nested inside something like ng-repeat) and add the view-head directive attribute. For example: <link view-head rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" href="{{rssUrl}}">
<meta view-head property="og:type" content="article">

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
document.title = 'Text';
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing your title in JS is tricky when dealing with search engines as you may get curly braces in search results or the title for the page won't be right. However, if you have a rendering server for Google/Bing/Yahoo!, then it'll show up right when crawled. That, however, is another issue entirely. In order to do this, move your `ng-app` directive to the `html` attribute:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <title ng-bind="titleService.currentTitle">My Default Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then create a service and bind it to the root scope:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .service('TitleService', function($location) {
    var DEFAULT_TITLE = 'My Default Title';
    return {
      setTitle: function(title) {
        this.currentTitle = title || DEFAULT_TITLE;
      }
    };
  });

angular.module('myApp').run(function(TitleService, $rootScope) {
  // This is mainly for a separation of concerns. These lines could
  // easily go in the service definition.
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', TitleService.setTitle);
  $rootScope.titleService = TitleService;
});
```

This assures that the default title will always be set by default. However, if you would like to set the title on a per-controller/directive basis you can do this inside of your code:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, TitleService, Article) {
     // I'm just guessing what your logic might look like
     var id = $location.search().articleId;
     Article.get(id).then(function(article){
        // Set the title however you want with article data
        TitleService.setTitle(article.title);
     });
  });
```

**EDIT:** I moved a line to the run function to separate the concerns of the service from the concerns of the application.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
document.title.innerHTML = "" //Text Goes in Quotes.
```

Good luck!