# Change the title on click of <li>

Tags: javascript, html

Following is code of menu and its script when i click on menu i want to chage the title of page...below code is not working...please help me...

```js
<script>
  function myFunction() 
  {  
    document.title = document.getElementsByClassName("MENU").text;
 }
</scipt>
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">About Us</a></li>

<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Rooms</a></li>
       
<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Reservation</a></li>

<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Gallery</a></li>
                            
<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Contact Us</a></li> 
       
</ul> <!-- /.menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
function myFunction() 
      { 
        document.title = event.target.text;
     }
```

```html
    <ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">About Us</a></li>

    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Rooms</a></li>
           
    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Reservation</a></li>

    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Gallery</a></li>
                                
    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction();">Contact Us</a></li> 
           
    </ul>
```

Comment: no its not working i tried this... will you please give me any other suggestion....

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>

<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="MENUNAME" href="javascript:;" >About Us</a></li>

<li><a class="MENUNAME" href="javascript:;" >Rooms</a></li>

<li><a class="MENUNAME" href="javascript:;">Reservation</a></li>

<li><a class="MENUNAME" href="javascript:;" >Gallery</a></li>

<li><a class="MENUNAME" href="javascript:;" >Contact Us</a></li> 

</ul> <!-- /.menu -->
<script>
 $(".MENUNAME").click(function(){

 document.title = $(this).html();
 });
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged in this question. It's always nice to have optional methods but  it would be a good idea to clearly point out this is a jQuery method.

Comment: when i used above code then it showing me default title given at title tag instead menu name...

Comment: did you need default title tag when page load?

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine for you.

> **Remove** the onclick attributes javascript will take care of the rest.

**Javascript**

```
function Events(){
var nav=document.getElementsByClassName('MENU');
//Set Event Listeners for all elements with the class MenuItem
for(var i=0; i<nav.length; i++){
nav[i].addEventListener('click',myFunction,false);
}
}
function myFunction(){
    document.title=event.target.innerHTML;
}

window.onload=Events;
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="MENU" href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a class="MENU" href="#">Rooms</a></li>                         
<li><a class="MENU" href="#">Reservation</a></li>
<li><a class="MENU" href="#">Gallery</a></li>                           
<li><a class="MENU" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>                        
</ul>
```

> **Note:** You don't need to add the onclick attribute on your menu elements. window.onload will call the Events function, this will set the onclick events for each element. myFunction will target the innerHTML of the element used to fire the function.

You can use `.innerHTML` **OR** `.text`

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, You can use `innerHTML` to get the `li` tag text

```
<script>
  function myFunction(d) 
  {  
    document.title = d.innerHTML;
 }
</script>

<ul class="menu">
    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction(this);">About Us</a></li>

    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction(this);">Rooms</a></li>

    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction(this);">Reservation</a></li>

    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction(this);">Gallery</a></li>

    <li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction(this);">Contact Us</a></li> 

</ul> <!-- /.menu -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the value into your function.getElementsByClassName just takes all class elements 'MENU'.
The following code worked for me:

```
<script>
  function myFunction(myValue) 
  {  
    document.title = myValue
 }
</script>
<ul class="menu">
<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction('About Us');">About Us</a></li>



<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction('Rooms');">Rooms</a></li>

<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction('Reservation');">Reservation</a></li>

<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction('Gallery');">Gallery</a></li>

<li><a class="MENU" href="#" onclick="javascript:myFunction('Contact Us');">Contact Us</a></li> 

</ul> <!-- /.menu -->
```

Note that you wrote your ending script wrong. change scipt to script.

Also note that this might not be the best way to change titles if we talk about SEO, see: [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: You don't **"have to"** pass the value to anything. You can get the innerHTML/text from the event. Also getElementsByClassName will step through like an array getElementsByClassName()[0] / getElementsByClassName()[1] / getElementsByClassName()[2]

Answer (score 0):

`$('.menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).attr("title", e.target.text);
});`

This will work. Please check if you are in a iframe or not. If you are in a iframe then it won't work it will set the title for that perticular iframe only.

Code below will set title for parent window of an iframe. However, make sure parent window and iframe are served from same domain.

`$('.menu li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.parent.document.title = e.target.text;
});`