# Changing text content depending on button clicked

Tags: html, server-side

I am sort of a beginner at this, but my objective is to have the header of my webpage changing, depending on what button was clicked on another page.

More precisely, I have a webpage with 7 buttons on it coded like this:

```
<form action="contribution.html">
    <input type="submit" style="margin-right: 80px;margin-top: 25px;" value="I contribute">
</form>
```

All of the buttons lead to the same "contribution.html" page, but I would like the header of that page to be different depending on what button the user clicked. There must be a way to do this without creating 7 different "contribution.html" pages for each button... I assume.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Are you planning on using a server sided Language such as PHP?

Comment: You could use something like JQuery to load new content into the header when the button is clicked.

Comment: Reason I ask is your question implicates loading another another page based on button clicked, Passing the variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a server-side language and `<a>` tags instead of a form.
In PHP it will look something like this:

```
<a href="/contribution.php?sum=10">10$</a>
<a href="/contribution.php?sum=20">20$</a>
<a href="/contribution.php?sum=30">30$</a>
```

etc.

Then on `contribution.php` you can get the request data from `$_GET['sum']` and act accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

When you do form submission server receives HTTP post request that contains button clicked. Having that request server side can generate proper content of `<title>` element. Browser will render that text in `<title>` as a caption of tab/page.

Thus you will need something like PHP or the like on your server. In this case you can have single contribution.php file (but not static html).

Answer (score 1):

Using javascript is the easiest solution. If you spend a little time learning jQuery, you could use something like this:

```
// A reference to your "header" element
var header = $('.header');

// When the submit button is clicked
$('[type=submit]').click(function(){
  // Update the header with the button's text
  header.text( $(this).value() );
});
```

Though I'd recommend using a more specific selector for the buttons you want this to work for, `[type-submit]` is too generic but I used it because you did.

Comment: I think the OP meant changing the header on `contribution.html`, not the page leading to it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your application and if you want to be SEO Friendly you should look into this answer [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)