# Changing title based on included file in PHP

Tags: php, include, title

I have to make some changes on my old website where I'm not using any templating system. I'm loading the content for some pages from a database based on `?page` parameter. So I have something like this:

```
<title>Page title</title>
...
...
...
$page_id = $_GET['page'];
include 'page.php'; //escaping is done in this file
```

Inside the `page.php` file I'm actually loading the information about the page. Based on this information I have to change the title of the main page.

I know that this design is not good at all and I wouldn't do this way these days, but to change everything on this website would be too complicated.

Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Add the code you are setting the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside page.php:

```
echo '<script>
document.title = "This is the new page title.";
</script>';
```

[How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Enjoy !

Answer (score 2):

Try to add php code before title

```
<html>
<?php
$page_id=$_GET["page"];
include('page.php');
echo "<title>".$page_title."</title>";
?>
<body></body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$page_id = $_GET['page'];
if ($page_id == 'first value') {
 $title = 'first title';
} else {
 $title = 'second title';
}
?>
<title><?php echo $title?></title>
...<?php
include 'page.php'; //escaping is done in this file
```