# can yo make the webpage title change again and again

Tags: javascript, jquery, title, titlebar, page-title

suppose I have a webpage with a title "Hi I am a title" but 5 seconds after the page has been loaded it becomes "Hi I am another title" and then 5 seconds after that it becomes "I am also a title" and then this keeps happening again and again.Can someone please guide me how to make this happen. I took some online tutorials from w3schools.com. I really want to do this but I don't even know where to start.

Comment: i have seen this happen on http://www.legworkstudio.com/

Comment: you need to have a background process that calls title changing fn every 5 sec. store iterator number in a variable and all the possible titles in an array. new title to give would be `array[iterator%array.length]`

Comment: i would apreeciate if you would type in a short example

Comment: Yes, but please don't.

Answer (score 4):

```
var i=0;
setInterval(function(){
    var titles=['Hi everyone', 'Salut tout le monde', 'Cao svima'];//add more titles if you want
    if(i===titles.length) {
        i=0;
    }
    document.title = titles[i];
    i++;
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 2):

The most complicated part of this code is using modulo to get the current iteration based on the length of the `titles` array.

```
(ii++ % titles.length)
```

We are increasing the iterator `ii++` then using modulo (division remainder) to figure out the current value of the iterator. This will allow you to use as many titles as you need.

```js
const titles = [
  'Hi I am a title',
  'Hi I am another title',
  'I am also a title'
]

function changeTitles(titles){
  // save an iterator in a closure
  let ii = 0
  // update is run at the start
  return (function update() {
    // change the title
    document.querySelector('title').textContent = titles[(ii++ % titles.length)]
    // queue the function to be called in 5 seconds
    setTimeout(update, 5000)
  })()
}

changeTitles(titles)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>hello</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var titles = ['title1', 'title 2', 'title 3'];

    var timeInterval = 5000; /** interval between each titles **/

    exec();

    setInterval(function(){
        exec();
    }, timeInterval * titles.length);

    function exec(){
        $.each(titles, function(k, v){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('title').html(v);
            }, timeInterval * (k + 1));
        });
    }

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), combined with setting the [document.title](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413455/695787).

To change the title dynamically, create an array of string messages (see [Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)). Inside the function you'll write for setInterval(), get a [random integer](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) everytime it runs. You can use that to index into the array of strings you've made. Set that value to document.title.

Or, here's some quick demo code to get you going:

```
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        messages = [ "one", "two", "three" ]

        function rotateTitle() {
            index = 0

            setInterval(function() {
                if (messages.length == index) {
                    index = 0
                }

                document.title = messages[index]

                index++
            }, 5000)
        }
    </script>
<body onLoad="rotateTitle()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thankyou Jameson but can yo show be example. I am not very good at DOM but i am learning

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work for you.

[The Demo on Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/32tt1p6q/1/)

The HTML (reload div for looks :P)

```
<div id="page_title"></div>
<br>
<span id="text-reload">Reload</span>
```

The JS

```
// custom jquery plugin loadText()
    $.fn.loadText = function( textArray, interval ) {
        return this.each( function() {
            var obj = $(this);
            obj.fadeOut( 'slow', function() {
                var elem = textArray[0];
                obj.empty().html( elem );
                textArray.shift();
                textArray.push(elem);
                obj.fadeIn( 'fast' );
            });
            timeOut = setTimeout( function(){ obj.loadText( textArray, interval )}, interval );
            $("#text-reload").click( function(){ 
                if( !obj.is(':animated') ) { clearTimeout( timeOut ); obj.loadText( textArray, interval );} // animation check prevents "too much recursion" error in jQuery 
            });
        });
    };

    $(document).ready(function() {
        var helloArray = ["Hi I am a title", "Hi I am another title", "I am also a title", "more", "and more", "and even more", "aloha", "see ya!"];
        $('#page_title').loadText( helloArray, 5000 ); // ( array, interval )
        document.title = $('#page_title').text();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<script>
        var titleArray = ["TITLE-1","TITLE-2","TITLE-3","TITLE-4"];
        var N = titleArray.length;
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(func,5000);
        function func(){
            if (i == 4) {
                i = 0;
            }
            document.title = titleArray[i];
            i++;
        }

</script>
```

Comment: thank you this works just fine but just one problem it takes 5 seconds for the first title to appear until then it is like file///C:User....................

Comment: I just figured it out I simply added <title>TITLE-1</title> above your script and it worked!!! Thank you rehan may Allah bless you