# How to change browser tab name dynamicaly by using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I'm developing an e-commerce website. When the user changes the tab and goes to another website. I want to change the page title and accordingly tab title too. For example, a user is on the main page and Title look like "Facebook" when a user goes to another page at same browser title should look something like "We miss you". Which javascript method can i use for it?
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title

Comment: so you mean that when the user navigates out of the current page, the tab title changes?

Comment: Yes That's right Umar, I meant that.

Comment: But the user would be on the same domain (your website)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Answer (score 0):

Run this snippet, and then click in and out of the results pane.  For those who insist on plain JS, now without any $.

```js
window.onblur = function() {
     //document.title = 'We Miss You';
     console.log('this works');
}

window.onfocus = function() {
     //document.title = 'We Miss You';
     console.log('this also works');
}
```

You can use a `blur` event:

```
$(window).blur(function() {
     document.title = 'We Miss You';
})
```

Then, when the user returns, use:

```
$(window).focus(function() {
     document.title = 'Facebook';
})
```

...to restore the original title

Comment: 1: This doesn't work, and 2: OP didn't ask for jQuery.. so better would be to answer with plain JS.

Comment: I suggest you try it.

Comment: @sideroxylon actually you have to stick with the OP question, otherwise, it is not an answer for the question, also no need to download library just to the simple job that can be done in plain JS, so you might need to ask in comments to get clarification before the answer.

Comment: The OP asked for a method.  The method is `blur` - that can be implemented via jQuery or plain JS.  I'm making no assumptions about what else is happening on the page - simply demonstrating that the `blur` and `focus` events can achieve the required outcome.  It's up to the OP (or anyone else) to decide how to implement those event.