# Userscript to strip a portion of a pages title

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

IMDb's reference view was recently changed to include "- Reference View - IMDb" after the page title that only used to have Movie (year)

New...

```
<title>Movie Title (2018) - Reference View - IMDb</title>
```

Old...

```
<title>Movie Title (2018)</title>
```

How do i strip the stuff they added to the reference pages so I just have Title (year)?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        IMDb - strip garbage from reference view page titles
// @match       *://www.imdb.com/title/tt*/reference
```

Code makes my head spin and the above is all I can manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of asking Google the right question. In your case, I searched for *"how to change html title with javascript"*, the first result was [javascript - How to dynamically change a web page's title? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title).

It's as simple as:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        IMDb - strip garbage from reference view page titles
// @match       *://www.imdb.com/title/tt*/reference
// ==/UserScript==

var newtitle = document.title;
newtitle = newtitle.replace(' - Reference View - IMDb','');
document.title = newtitle;
```