# How to change the window title after the 3 seconds delay by using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

**I need Change window title bar after 3 seconds delay**

*like this using javascript*
www.nazeer.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The following example is given Try This**

```js
setTimeout(()=>{
window.document.title = "Your OWn";
console.log("changing Title");

},3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the title using `document.title = "value"`

You can delay 3 seconds(3 * 1000 milliseconds) and then change using `setTimeout` function.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    document.title = "NEW TITLE"
}, 3000);
```

Here, 3000 is the time in milliseconds.

Refer this more queries - [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout( () => { window.document.title = 'Your title'}, 3000)
```

You can use `setTimeout` for delay, and `window.document.title` to change title/ Hope i help :)