# Changing document.title through JavaScript anonymous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am still a bit new to JavaScript. I am trying to dynamically change the title of a page through javascript. However I am getting a result of `undefined`. I have tried multiple things and still no luck. What is the right way to pass a value to this anonymous function?

```
let email = "myemail@email.com"
await page.evaluate(  (email) => document.title = email );
console.log(await page.title());
```

Comment: @skara9 sorry playwright js

Comment: add the tag to your question

Comment: why are you taking `email` as a param, shouldn't it be `() => document.title = email`

Comment: @skara9 I just want to pass that variable into that function to set the page title

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: You can't arbitrarily pass in variables to a callback that way. Did you try the way skara showed you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never used playwright js, but reading this documentation page here, https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating, it looks like you pass arguments for the anonymous function as the second, and next parameters, of the evaluation method:

```js
let email = "myemail@email.com"
await page.evaluate( (email) => document.title = email, email );
console.log(await page.title());
```

Comment: This answered my issue perfectly!

Comment: Also never used it, but presumably you can also use a closure, voiding the need for parameters in the first place: `await page.evaluate(() => document.title = email)`

Comment: @Amadan nah it runs in a different execution context, so it doesn't have access to external variables

Comment: @MaryCoding glad it helped. :)

Comment: Amadan and skara9 I am wondering that, too. Might be interesting to just try it. It's not impossible for a programming language to pass variables like that to inline functions. However, if it works here for playwright, I have no idea. ^^