# How webpages put the number of notification inside the page tab icon?

Tags: javascript, web

how to put the number of notification inside the web page tab icon?
for example how whatsapp put the number of new messages inside the whatsapp logo ?

[image: whatsapp web1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: no i was asking about the icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The icon in the tab is called a favicon, and it is set using a meta tag. The website changes the favicon to a new one every time the amount of messages changes. This is the code to change the favicon (which can usually be any image file):

```
document.querySelector("link[rel*='icon']").href = "[new favicon image url]";
```

You will need to have different images for each number of notifications. You can do it on the client side by generating images and using `createObjectURL` ([read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)), or you can have images and load them in from the server-side.