# Javascript how to change page title with user input

Tags: javascript, html

The thing i wanna do is when user writes something to input and sumbits it, the page will change to the input.

Example:

If user writes "Web" to the input, the page title should change to "Web"

Here's the code:

JS:

```
document.getElementById("titleSumbitBtn").onclick = function (){
    var newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").textContent;
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = newTitle;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title id="title">Web Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <center><label id="originLabel">Welcome to Web Editor!</label><br></center>
    <br><label id="changeTitleLabel">Change the title of Web: </label><br>
    <input type="text" id="newTitle"><br>
    <button type="button" id="titleSumbitBtn">Change</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: So _where_ does the JS code actually get embedded into the HTML document? I don't see a single `script` element anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assign new title to the document like this:

```
document.getElementById("titleSumbitBtn").onclick = function (){
    var newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
    document.title = newTitle;
}
```

This is actual implementation but keep in mind that it must run after the DOM element with id `newTitle`.

If you put your `<script>` tag inside `<head>`, you'll need `DOMContentLoaded`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    document.getElementById("titleSumbitBtn").onclick = function (){
        var newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
        document.title = newTitle;
    }
})
```

Comment: still doesn't work sadly.

Comment: it should work. i did an edit to the answer, did you tried the edited one?

Comment: yes, doesnt work

Comment: how do you use the javascript code in your file? script must be after the text input that you're trying to assign an onclick event, if you're not using dom content loaded event.

Comment: i forgot to put

<script src="index.js"></script>

that was the reason of error.

thanks for your help

Comment: Updated the answer with `DOMContentLoaded` example. Please accept the answer if it did help.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.getElementById("titleSumbitBtn").addEventListener("click", function (){
var newTitle = document.getElementById("newTitle").value;
document.getElementById("title").innerText = newTitle;
```

})