# How to change Title from Json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have a JSON file in my folders. I want to change the title value in index.html with the data in the JSON file.

I have a folder and there are 8 JSON files in this folder.

- de.json
- en.json
- es.json
- fr.json

The names of the variables in the JSON file are the same, but the content is different.

`"concurrent-deviceManagement-manage": "Device Management"`

`"concurrent-deviceManagement-manage": "Situngsverwaltung"`

`"concurrent-deviceManagement-manage": "Gestion des sessions"`

I want to replace the title data in the HTML with the content of the `"concurrent-deviceManagement-manage"` variable in this JSON file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically change a web page's title?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413439/how-to-dynamically-change-a-web-pages-title)

Comment: What have you already tried? Loading data from a .json file is pretty easy both in plain JS and in jQuery and turns that JSON into "just another JS object to work with" so where in this multi-step process (load json, get data from resultant object, update title) did you get stuck?

Comment: @Lordke did your issue sorted?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) and do something like this,

```
$.getJSON("de.json", function(data) {
  $("title").text(data["concurrent-deviceManagement-manage"]);
});
```

Updated:  With modern JS

As per the @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans suggestion, we can do something using like this:

```
fetch("de.json")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        document.title = data["concurrent-deviceManagement-manage"];
    });
```

[Read more about fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Although note that modern JS doesn't require jQuery here at all, the Fetch API can do this just fine.